# Database: Save `weight` and `height` in multiple measurements?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have an application where it saves the users' height and weight in the database. My tables are like below.

[image]

**unit_type** - The values of this table are `height`, `weight`

**units** - This table saves the related `unit_type` of the `patient` with related measurement value. For an example, `patient` id `1` may prefer **kg**  for measuring weight and **cm** for height. In that case, `units` table will have rows like below

```
idunits - 1
patient_idpatient - 1
unit_type_idunit_type - 1
unit_measurement - kg

idunits - 1
patient_idpatient - 1
unit_type_idunit_type - 2
unit_measurement - cm
```

I did not map `units` to any table, instead I ran a search query to find the user's preferred measurement and inserted data in other tables.

For an example, the `patient` table contains the `patinet`s **fixed** height and weight, which is a one time input (one patient will have only one record). So if I add a row into this table, it will look like below

```
idpatient - 1
height - 230
weight - 70
height_unit - cm
weight_unit - kg
```

For another example, the `measurement` table is used for patient's monthly `height` and `weight` readings. This will contain multiple records from the same patient. This will look like below

```
idmeasurements - 1
idpatient - 1
weight - 70
weight_measurement - kg

idmeasurements - 2
idpatient - 1
weight - 70
weight_measurement - kg

idmeasurements - 3
idpatient - 1
weight - 72
weight_measurement - kg
```

This approach was smooth till now, but we are facing a challenge. We were told that both `height` and `weight` should be saved in all measurements at once. For an example, if user is saving his weight in **kg**, then it should be saved in **lb** as well. If he is saving his `height` in **cm**, it should be saved in **inches** as well. This is because now the user can save his `height` and `weight` in his preferred measurement (ex: kg),  change the measurement into other available measure (ex: lb) and save another record while converting all former measurement values without loosing a single precision. He can do this up and down any number of times he want, no precision will be changed and we will not require to convert and update all of his values in DB every time from code as well.

My question is, how do I facilitate this? The only way I can think of 2 ways.

1. creating fields for every measurement type in all related tables. So in `patient` table, replace the existing columns with `height_cm`, `height_inches`, `weight_kg`, `weight_lb`. The same goes to `measurement` table. This may work for this scenario, but not sure whether the best practice. Imgine there are 1000 measurements for measuring weight/height (OK, that is pure imagination....) then what?
2. Create new tables for every measurement type. For an example, I can create `patient_weight` and `patient_height` tables and remove `height`, `weight`, `height_unit`, `weight_unit` fields from `patient` table.

My `patient_weight` table will look like below

```
idpatient_weight
idpatient
weight
measurement
```

So I can insert any number of measurements as I wish, converting same record into any number of measurements. Example is below

```
idpatient_weight - 1
idpatient - 1
weight - 70
measurement - kg

idpatient_weight - 2
idpatient - 1
weight - 154.32
measurement - lb
```

What do you suggest and recommend?

Comment: Completely wrong approach. The data should _not_ be saved parallel in different units, that creates redundant data and may actually lead to inconsistencies. Instead you should save only one type and compute the rest when required. Best is to always save in SI units internally.

Comment: Oh, and be careful, since that is a common cause of irritation: there are different types of certain units, for example pounds: in the US a pound is 450gr (AFAIK), the rest of the world uses a more sense making pound that comes to 500gr. So _be precise_ in your units too!

Comment: And another hint for the conversion between units: you should use a library for that, not code everything delocalized. I implemented something like that years ago. It currently only features lengths and areas, but is prepared to also provide conversions between weights, so maybe you are interested in extending it. The advantage of such a library is that it is much more robust and keeps to using code readable and easy to follow. This is my implementation back then: https://github.com/arkascha/php-urithmetic

Comment: @arkascha Thank you for the reply. Yes I know this is a wrong approach, but the requirement says the user should be able to save like that.. Today in 'kg' and tomorrow in 'lb' lf he needs. I know it is not practically gonna happen too. If the user gonna save in one unit and we were aksed to convert and display, that would be fine, but not the case here. Here the user will save in different measurements!! In case of measurement change, we can't convert eveything because it will change number precision after several converts and too hard as well. What di you suggest? Any alternative?

Comment: I typically found that sticking strictly to what is "asked" does not make sense and is _not_ what is expected from a good consultant. Nothing against a user making an input in different units. And certainly you can store those different inputs. But who says that you cannot convert them to a sane base unit? And btw: "too hard as well" is not really what you mean, is it?

Comment: @arkascha What about not changing anything and saving them as it is? For an example, in 'measurements' table one record will save 'weight' as 74 and 'measurement' as **kg**. Later user changes the measurement and save the next record as 'weight' 154.32 and 'measurement' as **lb**. When displaying, if user's prefered method is **lb** then programatically convert and display / calculate all 'weights' in **lb**. This way nothing will get saved in 2 units!

Comment: Sure, possible. However you like.

Comment: @arkascha regarding your comment on SI units, 'weight' and 'height' are not the only things jn real app. There are things like 'glukose' levels too! So SI base convertion might not a all rounding fit. So my above suggestion is a good approach?

Comment: Sure, don't stick to the literal word... Instead of "SI units" with "a sane internal base unit" or "the generally agreed upon base unit", whatever.

Comment: @arkascha: Actually, I am gonna save multiple units in same column, saving `measurement` field as **kg** if **kg** is selected; saving it as **lb** if **lb** is selected. Then when displaying, if **kg** is selected, I will display all **kg** values as it is and will convert all **lb** values to **kg** . Same goes to other way around.

Comment: Do you ever compute with the numbers?  Or are they purely echoed?  That is, would it work to save it as the _string_ "154.3 lb"?

Comment: @RickJames Yes we compute numbers. The "Weight " is a number like "50", "weight_unit" is a string like "kg"

Comment: But do you add to the 50?  Multiple it by something?  Take sqrt()?  If you never do anything but display it, then the string "50kg" is all that is ever needed.

Comment: @RickJames Actually, there are lot of operations in the applications side with numbers. Add, deduct, multiply or divide numbers.

Comment: Then I would pick a convention, such as SI, and convert on input (when needed) and convert on output (when needed).  I would use `FLOAT` if 7 significant digits would suffice.  I would avoid checking for equality -- because of conversion and rounding issues between `FLOAT` and "human readable" values, such as "154.32".  For simple display, I would `ROUND()` to a suitable number of decimal places -- eg, 1 (or maybe 0) for human weight in kg or lb.

Comment: @RickJames what I did and suggested above is something similar. I allowed to save the "unit" (kg/lb) when being saved. Then in retrieval,  if user is using "kg" as his measurement, i will convert all "lb" to "kg". The same for the other way around.